# eliminating bower and switching entirely to nuget based workload

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, nuget, bower

The following is the contents of my **bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "v4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "jquery": "2.1.4",
    "jquery-validation": "1.14.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.2",
    "ckeditor": "4.5.6"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery-validation": ">=1.8",
    "bootstrap": "v4.0.0-alpha.6"
  }
}
```

I tried eliminating the following dependency of jquery and asp.net from my **.csproj**.

I've done it by adding a reference of Jquery, bootstrap and ckeditor as nuget packages into my code.

**Error**

The command *"bower install"* **exited with code 9009.**

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying a build when you are getting: The command "bower install" exited with code 9009?

I removed the following code below in the project file (.csproj)

```
<Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
    <Exec Command="bower install" />
    <Exec Command="dotnet bundle" />
</Target>
```

However it did cause a couple of typescript issues with duplicate method names, add the below code to the tsconfig.json file

`"exclude": [
    "obj"
  ]`